Apparent dimensional problem when calculating a tensor contraction with matrices
According to Wikipedia is the bases vectors are fixed the two tensors $A$ and $B$ result in the tensor product given by the Kronecker multiplication:
$$A = \begin{bmatrix} 
a_{1,1} & a_{1,2} \\
a_{2,1} & a_{2,2}
\end{bmatrix}$$
$$B = \begin{bmatrix} 
b_{1,1} & b_{1,2} \\
b_{2,1} & b_{2,2}
\end{bmatrix}$$
$$\small T = A \otimes B =\small
\begin{bmatrix} 
a_{1,1} & a_{1,2} \\
a_{2,1} & a_{2,2}
\end{bmatrix} \otimes
\begin{bmatrix} 
b_{1,1} & b_{1,2} \\
b_{2,1} & b_{2,2}
\end{bmatrix} \\=\begin{bmatrix}
a_{1,1}\begin{bmatrix} 
b_{1,1} & b_{1,2} \\
b_{2,1} & b_{2,2}
\end{bmatrix} & 
a_{1,2}\begin{bmatrix} 
b_{1,1} & b_{1,2} \\
b_{2,1} & b_{2,2}
\end{bmatrix} \\
a_{2,1}\begin{bmatrix} 
b_{1,1} & b_{1,2} \\
b_{2,1} & b_{2,2}
\end{bmatrix} &
a_{2,2}\begin{bmatrix} 
b_{1,1} & b_{1,2} \\
b_{2,1} & b_{2,2}
\end{bmatrix}
\end{bmatrix}
=
\begin{bmatrix} 
a_{1,1}b_{1,1} & a_{1,1}b_{1,2} & a_{1,2}b_{1,1} & a_{1,2}b_{1,2} \\
a_{1,1}b_{2,1} & a_{1,1}b_{2,2} & a_{1,2}b_{2,1} & a_{1,2}b_{2,2} \\
a_{2,1}b_{1,1} & a_{2,1}b_{1,2} & a_{2,2}b_{1,1} & a_{2,2}b_{1,2} \\
a_{2,1}b_{2,1} & a_{2,1}b_{2,2} & a_{2,2}b_{2,1} & a_{2,2}b_{2,2}
\end{bmatrix}
$$
I presume that $T$ would have two upper and two lower indices, as in $T^{ij}_{\phantom{ij}kl}$.
Now I should be able to contract $i$ and $k,$ equivalently of taking the trace of the $A$ matrix and multiplying it by $B$, i.e. $\mathop{Tr}(A)B$. This would correspond to $T^{ij}_{\phantom{ij}il}$.
Given that each matrix $A$ and $B $ is $2 \times 2$, this would have to reduce the last matrix above from its $4 \times 4$ dimensions.
How would this be implemented in a given numerical calculation if there is no possibility to recover the initial coefficients of $A$ and $B$?
The entries involved appear in the final matrix already multiplied with entries of $B$:
$$
\begin{bmatrix} 
\color{red}{a_{1,1}}b_{1,1} & \color{red}{a_{1,1}}b_{1,2} & a_{1,2}b_{1,1} & a_{1,2}b_{1,2} \\
\color{red}{a_{1,1}}b_{2,1} & \color{red}{a_{1,1}}b_{2,2} & a_{1,2}b_{2,1} & a_{1,2}b_{2,2} \\
a_{2,1}b_{1,1} & a_{2,1}b_{1,2} & \color{red}{a_{2,2}}b_{1,1} & \color{red}{a_{2,2}}b_{1,2} \\
a_{2,1}b_{2,1} & a_{2,1}b_{2,2} & \color{red}{a_{2,2}}b_{2,1} & \color{red}{a_{2,2}}b_{2,2}
\end{bmatrix}
$$
I am not asking for an answer along the lines of "that is why using matrices is not a good idea", but I want to understand why there is no contradiction, and how this would work in higher order tensors by extension.

The Wikipedia article is slightly confusing by omitting some brackets from the final tensor. It looks like a $4\times4$ matrix, i.e., a rank $2$ tensor with $4^2=16$ entries, but actually it is a $2\times2\times2\times2$ tensor of rank $4$ having $2^4=16$ entries. Contraction happens by taking the trace of four $2\times2$ "submatrices" separately:
$$\begin{bmatrix} 
\hbox{Tr}\begin{bmatrix}a_{1,1}b_{1,1} & a_{1,2}b_{1,1}\\
a_{2,1}b_{1,1} & a_{2,2}b_{1,1}\end{bmatrix}
&
\hbox{Tr}\begin{bmatrix}a_{1,1}b_{1,2} & a_{1,2}b_{1,2} \\
a_{2,1}b_{1,2} & a_{2,2}b_{1,2}
\end{bmatrix}
\\
\hbox{Tr}\begin{bmatrix}a_{1,1}b_{2,1} & a_{1,2}b_{2,1}\\
a_{2,1}b_{2,1} & a_{2,2}b_{2,1}\end{bmatrix}
&
\hbox{Tr}\begin{bmatrix}a_{1,1}b_{2,2} & a_{1,2}b_{2,2}\\
a_{2,1}b_{2,2} & a_{2,2}b_{2,2}\end{bmatrix}
\end{bmatrix}$$

This makes perfect sense. Thank you! As a quick follow-up question, what would be the mechanics if instead I wanted to contract $j$ and $l$, or $i$ and $l$ in $T^{ij}_{\phantom{kj}kl}$? (Unless it is worth a different question, or can't be answered in a quick couple of lines).

You would still take traces of 4 submatrices at a time, only different ones.

What is the system behind rearranging the block matrices?

Interesting how all the info from the entries not involved in the contraction is literally thrown out... Tempting to say "no trace of it". So all that matters is the correct arrangements of the indices involved, which outside the constraints of a matrix, it would not be relevant...

It also makes the answer here incorrect. We are calculating 4 traces, not just one!

I have to qualify my above comment that it is always traces of submatrices. That holds if you contract over the two indices of $A$ or over the two indices of $B,$ but if you contract over, say, $i$ and $l$ then you would have a matrix product.

The system behind rearranging the block matrices is that the grouping (in order to write the tensor as a $4\times4$ matrix) involves an arbitrary choice of two indices, and the contraction may be over a different pair of indices.

Any contraction throws out information from all components where the two indices involved in the contraction have different values. The ordinary trace of a square matrix is just the simplest example of that.

The answer that you refer to, remains correct. We only appear to take $4$ different traces; if you apply the distributive law then we are only taking the trace of $A,$ multiplied by the four components of $B$ separately. But I wrote it this way because you asked for a computation that did not rely on separate knowledge of $A$ or $B.$

I see! Regarding this answer: $a_{11}b_{11} + a_{22}b_{11}=-1 + (-3) = -4$, $a_{11}b_{12} + a_{22}b_{2}=0 + 0 = 0$, $a_{11}b_{21} + a_{22}b_{21}=1 + 3 = 4$ and $a_{11}b_{22} + a_{22}b_{22}=2+ 6 = 8$, which are the traces in your answer, and correspond to $\text{Tr}(Y)Z=4 \begin{pmatrix}-1&0\1&2\end{pmatrix}$.

I have posted a follow-up question here to the comment "That holds if you contract over the two indices of A or over the two indices of B, but if you contract over, say, i and l then you would have a matrix product." It would be great if you decided to answer it. Thanks again!
